# How to log if data has been send to database

Tags: php, laravel, logging, monolog

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and know about the Monolog package.

My question now is, since I haven't found a proper tutorial on correctly logging your data, how do I properly log if the user input, converted into an array, is sent to the database?

The array is quite big, so I don't see any use in logging this whole thing, but I want to make sure the array has been passed to the database(using API package for the db connection and the methods to save the data).

Any idea how I can log if the data was sent correctly? (and of course log it, when something went wrong)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DB::listen` inside a provider, like the docs suggest. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#listening-for-query-events

This would log every query done to your database but what you *should* use  to ensure the data sent by an user is correct is validation, probably in the form of Form Requests. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: The Database I'm talking about is FileMaker, so I don't think this would work. And I'm using Form Requests, but I just want to be sure if it worked correctly.

Comment: Googling reveals a package to add a driver for FileMaker.  (https://github.com/andreossido/laravel-filemaker) which depends on laravel-odbc (https://github.com/andreossido/laravel-odbc). Perhaps using those, you may use the DB facade to listen in on queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you using on local install, try to get the [telescope package](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/telescope). This package installs a logger ambient with a good approach not only in database, but, in a series of points inside laravel.